# PHP mail() in dev environment: open the mail in a browser/editor instead of sending it?

Tags: email, php

On my machine I need to test the mails sent by my application. I'd rather avoid sending real mails.

Is there a way to have the email content showed to the screen a way or another, maybe by opening it in gedit or any text editor?

Maybe like replacing the commandline used to launch "sendmail"?

I am asking for Linux machines (Ubuntu more specifically).

Comment: Write a wrapper class for sending mail in PHP, and use that instead of calling `mail()` directly. Then it's easy; your wrapper class can simply check whether it's in dev mode or not, and decide how to process the message. (note, PHP's `mail()` function is pretty awful; a wrapper class would be a good idea anyway, even if you don't want to do this sort of thing. you might want to try out phpMailer or Swiftmail instead)

Comment: @Spudley please read the existing answer, and its comments

Comment: fair enough. For what it's worth, I'd consider anyone using the plain `mail()` function without some kind of wrapper to be crazy, with or without this kind of requirement. But that's a separate debate. :) If you're looking for a server-level solution, outside of your codebase, you might consider asking your question on one of the more server-oriented sites in the Stackoverflow family (see the lists at the footer of this page); you might find more expert help there (SO is mainly populated by programmers, and while most of us may know our way around a command line, we're not sys admins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, here is the solution I came to:

- create a script that will fake a smtp server

`/usr/local/bin/sendmail-fake`:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
date
echo $@
cat
} >> /var/log/sendmail-fake.log
```

- configure PHP:

php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/sendmail-fake
```

In this setup, emails are logged into a file. The script could be modified to open the content into a browser.

More details on [the blog post](http://mnapoli.fr/working-with-mails-in-dev-environment/).

Answer (score 0):

Include a means of determining your environment in your project, or at least some kind of global variable that holds that information.

Then build an abstract mail interface that either sends real mails if it's running on a production server, but logs them to local files in case it runs on a dev machine / environment. As a logging package, I would recommend [Monolog](https://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog).

This would allow you to design the rest of your application (or at least the mail sending components) in a way that doesn't have to care about the environment.

Comment: Actually I thought of a more low-level configuration, not PHP code. Maybe by configuring/mocking sendmail in the php.ini config.

Comment: Since you asked for an OS independent solution, any Linux tricks that would achieve your goal aren't an answer as well, so I would go for a high-level solution via code.

Comment: I updated the question, I was only curious if solution existed for Mac or Windows but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Another argument for no code is that I don't want to impact other developers of my team.